# How many laptops can I take to UK?

Tags: air-travel, uk, customs-and-immigration, electronic-items

I'll be traveling to England with a stopover in Dubai. I'm a student going to study in England and have two laptops (both Macbook Pros) and of course they're for my own use (can't seem to transfer the data from my old one to the new one so thats why Im taking both of them) and I was wondering if taking both of these would cause any problems at customs?

Comment: Obvious question: how old are they, what resale value do they have? I imagine two brand new $6000 top-of-the-line fully-loaded 2017 MBPs could get treated differently to two ancient ones.

Answer (score 2):

You are taking two laptops for a plausible reason, which is to study in the UK, and the laptops are interdependent upon each other for data and analysis.

If you do not intend to sell these laptops, then we can turn to the guidance which says in part...

> You can bring some goods from abroad without having to pay UK tax or
>   ‘duty’ (customs charges), as long as they’re for your own use.

Source: [Bringing goods into the UK](https://www.gov.uk/duty-free-goods)

If challenged, you can be prepared to show that they are in use to support your studies.  No big problems here.